# What is the meaning for "Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option "

Tags: errors, packages

I load the following packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amscd}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{upref}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

Could any one can tell me why when I run the latex, it always has error:

```
Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm',
(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.
```

How should I fix this problem?

(Besides, I can see the PDF file of the paper, and it seems there is no error in the file.)

Comment: The `dvipdfm` suggests you are targeting `latex` + `dvipdfmx`, while the error says you are running `pdflatex`!

Comment: Note that `hyperref` should go last in your list of loaded packages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are running `pdflatex` or `lualatex` in PDF mode (second line of the error message), but you have specified a driver `dvipdfm`, which only works for DVI output (second line of the error message).

Since `hyperref` can detect the correct driver here (`hpdftex.def`), the error recovery works by ignoring the wrong driver specification.

If you want to compile the document both with `pdflatex`/`lualatex` and `latex/dvipdfm`, then option `driverfallback` can be used:

```
\usepackage[driverfallback=dvipdfm]{hyperref}
```

Then `hyperref` uses the driver for `pdflatex`/`lualatex`, if it detects them.
Otherwise `dvipdfm` is chosen.

Comment: Wow! That works perfectly! Thank you for your wonderful answer!!!!