# Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips', (hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, dvips

I wanted to compile the template for the Journal Statistics in Medicine (the template can be found here: [SIMDOC.TEX](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291097-0258/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm)). I am using TeXWorks on Ubuntu. I got the following error: `! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option dvips, (hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.`
 I've seen some related questions such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236655/what-is-the-meaning-for-package-hyperref-error-wrong-dvi-mode-driver-option). I think the problem comes from the following  code:`\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}`, because when I delete `dvips` it works fine.
How should I compile this template to avoid getting an error ( without deleting `dvips`).
Can someone describes the correct procedure of compiling it for me? Thanks.

Comment: You do want to delete `dvips`, assuming you are directly creating a PDF file (`pdflatex`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can remove the dvips, it will do no harm. But if you want to submit to this journal, you should ask them if there still want postscript -- this affects the type of graphics you can use.